# What does it mean to say "Solr will not analyze queries"?

Tags: solr, lucene

Came across this statement "Solr does not analyze wildcard queries" [here](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/).

I'm reading this that when a * or ? is detected, then anything in the analyzer type="query" sequence doesn't get run.  Does that apply to the tokenizer as well?

Comment: Edited to remove the angle brackets around analyzer type=query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that Analysis does not take place when a wildcard query is applied is a good rule (and I've said so many times myself), but slightly wrong.

The exact explanation is that [any tokenizer or filter that isn't MultiTermAware will be excluded](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analyzers#Analyzers-AnalysisforMulti-TermExpansion), so Solr tries to "do the right thing" without them. You can define your own analysis chain under the key `type="multiterm"` (with only MultiTermAware components) to define a custom chain for multitermed queries (such as wildcards).

The only [tokenizer that is multitermaware as of 6.3 is LowerCaseTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LowerCaseTokenizerFactory.html). In addition KeywordTokenizer will work, since it results in a single token.

You can see the [whole list of MultitermAware components in the 'implemented by' list of the API doc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/MultiTermAwareComponent.html).